# ASP.net SQL database amend existing string field data using command parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, command, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to maintain a log field (fldUserLog ) of my database table so that when updating each raw, the log field will be amended with given log string.

Log string

```
 strUserLog = "Added by : " & Session("auth_Id") & " at " & Now() & " from IP " &
      Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & vbCrLf
```

and I am using SQL command parameters to UPDATE query. as follows

```
strSQLQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET " _
    & "fldTitle  = @xTitle, " _
    & "fldDesc  = @xDesc, " _
    & "fldUserLog = fldUserLog + @xUserLog " _
    & "WHERE fldId = @xId ;"

strMessage = "updated"

ObjAddDB.setCommand(strSQLQuery)
With ObjAddDB
    .setParameters("@xTitle", frmTitle.Text)
    .setParameters("@xDesc", frmDesc.Text)
    .setParameters("@xUserLog", strUserLog)
    .setParameters("@xId", MyItemId)
End With
```

Please note that **setCommand** and **setParameters** are my own methods I am using in my database.vb class file.

I get following error when its executed

> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Incorrect syntax near 'fldUserLog'.

please help me to use my UPDATE query to amend existing data with command parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the `fldUserLog` field value contains spaces, you need to embrace the value with `[ ]` ..

```
& "fldUserLog = [fldUserLog @xUserLog] " _
```

I guess what you may want to write is the following:

```
& "fldUserLog = @xUserLog " _
```